# How to prevent jQuery UI draggable to increase width of the page and drag to parent HTML from iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I noticed when using jQuery UI draggable and dragging the object to the right side of the screen, that it resizes my whole body.

You can try it on this page: [jQuery UI Draggable](http://html-generator.weebly.com/jquery-draggable.html)

You can drag the "drag me around box" further and further to the right. How can I prevent this? I dont want to use `containment`, because it should continue dragging from inside the iframe to its parent with the option `iframeFix: true`.

Thank you

Here you have my problem: I made an image [image: draggable object inside iframe to parent html]

Comment: I see your problem with the resizing, but I don't see why you don't want to set the `containment: 'body'`.  Please explain further.

Comment: When dragging to the right, the iframe width increases, so I can never reach the parent html container.

Comment: I am not sure if `.iFrameFix` can do what you want.  Here's a link to it's [docs (jqueryui.com)](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-iframeFix).  I don't think it is possible to have the draggable come out of it's `<iframe>` parent.

Comment: I was hoping, that it enables dragging a cross iframe and parent objects.

Comment: overflow:hidden has no effect.

Comment: I managed to stop the scrolling with the option `scroll:false`, but my problem dragging across an iframe still exists. I am trying some workaround with checking the boundaries of the iframe. Still no elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Literally just had this problem with a ton of divs on a background.

I added a touchmove listener to the background and set it to preventDefault() and return false;

This stopped the parent resizing when my panels were dragged out of the edge of the screen.

Probably a bit late, but maybe useful for future reference.

```
handleContentScroll:function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I used HTML5 Drag & Drop to fix this problem.